# not able to remove item level user permission using CSOM

Tags: csom, 2016

I am trying to remove item level permission using csom

Below is my code

```
    folderCollection = rootWeb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(URL).Folders;
     foreach (Folder f in folderCollection){ 
                  f.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance(false, true);
                  User user= rootWeb.EnsureUser(uemail);
                  f.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipal(user).DeleteObject();
                  f.Update();
                  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

It throws the below error

> Unable to find the principal whose ID is 30

What have i missed? will only groups be available in `getbyprincipal`?

Comment: There is no *Remove* function for ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments as existing in the PowerShell, and the ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipal(user).DeleteObject(); should working with users + group, so the question here **Are you sure this user already has a custom permission for this folder?** may be the current folder in folderCollection didn't have custom permission,